Process currency signs as text
I am battling with a website that looks like this (Minimal Reproducible Example):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MathJax Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" defer="" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.MathJax = {
    loader: {
      load: ['[tex]/boldsymbol'],
    },
    tex: {
      packages: {
        '[+]': ['boldsymbol'],
      },
      inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
      processEscapes: true
    },
  };



</script>
<script defer="" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/input/tex/extensions/boldsymbol.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The price: \( €0.7 \)</p>
</body>
</html>

Through a browser, the price appears as "Math input error", because of the € sign.
Obviously, the body should be like this, and I would have no problem:
<p>The price: \( \text{€0.7} \)</p>

For various irrelevant reasons, I cannot modify the body of the html, however I can modify the head.
Can anyone help me find a solution so that these badly formatted math input appears as intended?

Use this :


Use this :  inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\f(', '\f)']],

Instead of : inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],



Form feed (/f) is commonly used to begin new sections in printed texts, providing a simple yet effective method for controlling page breaks.
This is the desired output with (/f)


Your solution changes the delimiters for the math, and so MathJax will no longer process the math at all.  While that prevents the error, it also prevents typesetting any inline math.  This really has nothing to do with form feeds in  particular, as you could have accomplished this by changing the '\\(' to anything different.  But I don't think this is a real solution as it effectively disables the math typesetting rather than allowing the typesetting to process error free.

Also, your output is not the "desired output", which would not include the \( and \), as those are the math delimiters that should be removed when the math is typeset.

You can add a TeX input jax pre-filter that inserts the \text{} command around the Euro symbol.  Here is an example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>MathJax Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.MathJax = {
    startup: {
      ready() {
        MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
        MathJax.startup.document.inputJax[0].preFilters.add(({math}) => {
          math.math = math.math.replace(/\u20AC/g, '\\text{\u20AC}');
        });
      }
    },
    loader: {
      load: ['[tex]/boldsymbol'],
    },
    tex: {
      packages: {
        '[+]': ['boldsymbol'],
      },
      inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The price: \( €0.7 \)</p>
</body>
</html>



This is all done in the document head, so I think that satisfies your conditions.
